# Should I use “which one” “of which one” “one was” or “one of which” for the following sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, relative-clauses, phrase-choice

Should I use “which one” “of which one” “one was” or “one of which” for the following sentence

> Nathaniel Hawthorne wrote four novels ... ‘The Scarlet Letter’ became an American literary icon.

Comment: "...four novels of which one, _The Scarlet Letter_, became an American literary [what?]" - OR "...four novels, one of which,..."

Comment: @KateBunting: I filled in the blank, but it did give me pause for thought. Although *The Scarlet Letter* could be ***called*** "an American literary **masterpiece**", I don't think it quite works to say it ***became*** a masterpiece. In fact, the *only* word I can think of to work with ***becoming*** is ***icon***.

Comment: ...on second thoughts, *became a ... **success, best-seller.*** Or (maybe?) ***triumph***.